# Find the range of values which has no real solutions

Tags: roots, quadratics

I would like to know how to solve the following problem:

> Find the range of values of the parameter $m$ for which the equation $2x^2 - mx + m = 0$ has no real solutions.

I know I have to use the quadratic formula and the response is $0 < m < 8$.
But what I don't know is how to proceed to find this answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't **have** to use the quadratic formula. Since\begin{align}2x^2-mx+m&=2\left(x-\frac m4\right)^2+m-\frac{m^2}8\\&=2\left(x-\frac m4\right)^2+\frac{8m-m^2}8\end{align}it s clear that your equation has no roots if and only if $8m-m^2>0$. And, since $8m-m^2=m(8-m)$, this occurs if and only if $m\in(0,8)$.

Comment: If you multiply first by $8=4\times 2$ (four times the coefficient of $x^2$) it has the effect of clearing fractions. But this procedure of simply competing the square is the simplest and also makes it easier to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- A quadratic equality has no real solution if and only the discriminant is negative.
- First, find the discriminant, find out when is it negative.

Answer (score 1):

If you rearange equation like this $$m= {2x^2\over x-1}$$ you must figer out for witch $m$ graph of $f(x) = {2x^2\over x-1}$ does not cuts the line $y=m$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: A quadratic equation has no real roots iff the discriminant is negative.

$$\Delta = b^2-4ac$$

$$\Delta < 0 \implies b^2-4ac < 0$$

The given quadratic equation is $$\color{blue}{2}x^2\color{purple}{-m}x\color{green}{+m} = 0$$

Identifying what $a$, $b$, and $c$ are, you only have to set $b^2-4ac < 0$ and see what values of $m$ satisfy that condition.